# How do I include 0-rated items while ranking items with variable number of ratings?

Tags: bayesian, ranking

I have a list of items and ratings from 0 to 10, with decimal ratings so that possible ratings are 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 ... 9.5, 10.
I am using https://www.evanmiller.org/ranking-items-with-star-ratings.html, but that considers ratings from 1 to K. How do I modify it to consider 0 rating for items.

Answer (score 0):

You have $K=21$ ratings in this case, and the correspondence is:

$$\text{Rating}_i = 0.5 (i-1)
\quad \quad \quad \quad 
\text{for } i = 1,...,21.$$

Comment: Thanks. At i=1, Rating = 0 and s<sub>k</sub>=0   => so there would be no difference between an item having a 0 rating and having no rating when I plug the numbers into the equation. What would be the best way to handle that.

Comment: I cannot understand what you have written here.

Comment: The formula uses a weighted-average for the rating ~ sk * (nk+1) where sk is the weight of the rating (equal to the rating) and nk is the number of k-ratings. At k = 0, as sk = 0, the equation calculates to 0, so the nk ratings of 0 are not being taken into account. For example, if the ratings were - (i) 1* -- 30 ppl, 3* -- 40 ppl, and (ii) 0* -- 100 ppl, 1* -- 30 ppl, 3* --40 ppl,  there would be no difference between (i) and (ii) as per the formula.

Comment: The linked material does not appear have a value for "no rating" so there is no correspondence between $s_k=0$ and "no rating".  If you wanted to introduce a category for "no rating" then that would be a missing data problem.